# stm32 audio levels

Tags: audio, stm32, dac, stm32f7

I'm using an STM32F746G for exploring embedded audio DSP.  My experiments sound great in headphones but when I connect the audio output to external amplifiers, the signal level is low and there's a lot of whine to don't hear in phones.

I'm using the same output jack (CN10).  It's described in the manual both as a "line out" and a "headphone out."  Reading about headphone levels it seems like they should be decent for line level although I thought I might need to pad a few dB.

Any tricks or tips to using that as a line out?  Unique DAC config?  Blocking caps?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you consulted the manual of that eval board http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/c6/6e/70/0a/25/f2/45/7c/DM00188496.pdf/files/DM00188496.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00188496.pdf ? It says which audio codec is used. You should look that codec up and find its datasheet.

Comment: In my rich fantasy life I was going to fly above that and just use the BSP functions.  In the ref manual I see cryptic mention of: "Each DAC channel output buffer can be enabled and disabled using the corresponding BOFFx bit in the DAC_CR register."  Still looking for details...

Comment: STM32F746G Discovery is the full name of the dev kit.  Didn't realize there was ambiguity.  Sorry.  I see one reference in HAL code for setting the BOFFx of the DAC_CR but that routine never gets called.  The chip is the Wolfson WM8994 apparently.

Comment: No ambiguity; I was just overreading the fact that there was no `F` in the middle.

Comment: Is there any chance the headphone output is class D and the lack of an apparent signal there as a "line output" is due to lack of inductive/capacitive loading?  I'm still wading through the datasheet for the DAC but it's pretty darn complex.  Also, although it seems to match what I see in code, it doesn't, at a glance, match the reference manual for the STM32Fn eval boards.

Answer (score 1):

I think this just comes down to "no attention given to audio signal path" as there's a lot of apparent crosstalk between the input and output and I have to keep levels artificially low.  Btw, no class D.  Looked at signal with a scope. I don't think there's a panacea for this; just use another board if you're doing serious audio.